# Select from 2 database remove same column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to select all the values of table 1 from the first database that are not present in table 2 from the second database. I tried the code below, but DISTINCT does not work:

```
select DISTINCT(affected_ci),ci_name from sitequota.incidents,appwarehouse.ci_table where incidents.affected_ci <> ci_table.ci_name


DATABASE1: APPWAREHOUSE
TABLE1:    CI_TABLE
COLUMN:    CI_NAME


DATABASE2:  SITEQUOTA
TABLE2:     INCIDENTS
COLUMN:     AFFECTED_CI
```

Comment: Please don't shout, and could you describe the problem some more than just "is not working"?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is meant by not working? Do you get an error? Or you get the output other than expected? Please, edit your question with more details

Comment: select affected_ci,ci_name from sitequota.incidents, ci_table where incidents.affected_ci <> ci_table.ci_name

Comment: it has multiple queries

Comment: i tried this but distinct doesnt work select DISTINCT(affected_ci),ci_name from sitequota.incidents,appwarehouse.ci_table where incidents.affected_ci <> ci_table.ci_name

Comment: You cannot apply DISTINCT to just one column. It affects the whole row. So, in your case it will remove the rows that are fully identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT ci_name
FROM appwarehouse.ci_table
WHERE ci_name NOT IN
  (SELECT affected_ci FROM sitequota.incidents
  )
```